# Is it impossible to limit journalctl to a user service?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

I am specifically **NOT** asking about how a user can look at their own logs, I am asking how at root level, where I see user service logs with a plain call to `sudo journalctl --output with-unit` like so:

`Wed 2024-02-21 18:28:55 CET hostname user@1012.service/foo-bar.service[3387594]: ------------------- Bla ------------------------------------------------------`

Things I have attempted:

```
sudo journalctl -u user@1012.service/foo-bar.service
Invalid unit name "user@1012.service/foo-bar.service" escaped as "user@1012.service-foo-bar.service" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?).
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u user@1012.service
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u foo-bar.service
-- No entries --

systemd-escape user@1012.service/foo-bar.service
user\x401012.service-foo\x2dbar.service

sudo journalctl -u user\x401012.service-foo\x2dbar.service
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u user\x401012.service
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u foo\x2dbar.service
-- No entries --
```

I have attempted the same, with the same result, using `--user-unit` instead of `-u`.

I don't understand how it can output the line, but not filter for it. Is this a bug in SystemD ?